# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Swift and simple struct

Tags: swift, macos

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

  var onlineTunnels:[Tunnel]? = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let t = Tunnel(
      id: "id",//tunnel["id"] as? String,
      ip: "127.0.0.1",
      proto: "tcp",//tunnel["proto"] as? String,
      region: "us",//tunnel["region"] as? String,
      public_url: "http://localhost",//tunnel["public_url"] as? String,
      metadata: "1",
      started_at: "started_at",//tunnel["started_at"] as? String,
      version: "1")

    onlineTunnels?.append(t)
  }

}
```

I'm seeing Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).  Could someone help me understand why I'm seeing this?  Eventually, I will setup a loop and add multiple tunnels into the array and then show them in an NSTableView.  Thoughts?  Its breaking where I append the struct to the array and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Which line is it crashing on? What's the backtrace?

Comment: Your code checks out fine so your issue probably lies elsewhere. You need to give us more specific details on your crash.

Comment: Only thing that jumps out to me is the `IBOutlet` might not be connected properly, but it's hard to say for sure without more details.

Comment: Unrelated but why is `onlineTunnels` optional as you clearly assign an item in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, OP's not doing anything w/ `tableView` (at least in the code shown), so technically that can't be it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery If the `IBOutlet` wasn't connected then it would say `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil...`

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Its breaking where I'm adding the struct to the array.  I don't understand why though.

Comment: Please post the backtrace.

Comment: I got this fixed up the other day.  I had accidentally linked my onlineTunnels variable in the storyboard to the ViewController and it caused the violation.